# Socket file transfer file lock issue with Delphi

Tags: sockets, delphi, file-transfer

I have a problem. When i getting a file from server, even my file is downloaded but i get an error "this file is using by another applications"

Edit: i am sorry my code was missing. This is server part. I am executing this method after startup. and its wait a command from clients. goto is a label. ıf job (for example "file start") is finished then clean and free connections. This is multi thread socket application. Repeat until for part of file downloading. i hope i would explained.

my codes

```
procedure ConnectionWorker(P: Pointer);
label cleanup;
Var
  sData1: TStringDYNArray;
  cSock: TClientSocket;
  scHost, scSendData, scFirstData, scFullData:String;
  sBuff, sString:String;
  bPackInfos:TPacketInformation;
  scByte, sComm:Byte;
  sBitMap:TBitmap;
  sJPEG:TJPEGImage;
  fFile:TFileStream;
  scPort,lRecvLen, cRead, x,y:Integer;
  arrBuffer:array[0..1000] of Byte;
  bBuff:array[0..4095] of Byte;
  eRatio:Extended;
  sFirstCap, sDifCap, sSecondCap, sCompStream:TMemoryStream;
  pCompStream:TCompressionStream;
  cThread, cKillThread:Cardinal;
Begin
  scHost := PInfo(P)^.scHost;
  scSendData := PInfo(P)^.scData;
  scPort := PInfo(P)^.scPort;
  scByte := PInfo(P)^.scPackHead;
  sFirstCap := TMemoryStream.Create;
  sSecondCap := TMemoryStream.Create;
  cSock := TClientSOcket.Create;
  cSock.Connect(scHost,scPort);
  if cSock.Connected then begin
    scFirstData := scSendData;
    If SendPacket(cSock,scByte, scFirstData) then begin
      repeat
        scFullData := '';
        ZeroMemory(@arrBuffer[0], 1001);
        lRecvLen := cSock.ReceiveBuffer(arrBuffer[0],1001);
        if cSock.Connected = false then break;
        SetLength(sBuff,lRecvLen);
        MoveMemory(@sBuff[1],@arrBuffer[0],lRecvLen);
        scFullData := scFullData + sBuff;
        repeat
          bPackInfos := VerifyPacket(scFullData);
          scFullData := bPackInfos.PacketLeft;
          sString := bPackInfos.PacketCommand;
          sComm := bPackInfos.PacketByte;
          if bPackInfos.PacketFinished = False then
            break;
          case sComm of

            PACK_QUERYCOMPRESSEDFILE:
              begin
                if FileExists(sString) then begin
                  try
                    sFirstCap.LoadFromFile(sString);
                    sFirstCap.Position := 0;
                    sCompStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
                    pCompStream := TCompressionStream.Create(clMax,sCompStream);
                    pCompStream.CopyFrom(sFirstCap, sFirstCap.Size);
                    pCompStream.Free;
                    sString := '';
                    SetLength(sString,sCompStream.Size);
                    SendPacket(cSock,PACK_COMPRESSEDTRANSFERFILE,IntToStr(sCompStream.Size));
                    sCompStream.Position := 0;
                    sCompStream.Read(sString[1],sCompStream.Size);
                    SendPacket(cSock,PACK_COMPRESSEDDOWNLOADFILE,sString);
                  except
                    SendPacket(cSock,PACK_COMPRESSEDTRANSFERFILE,IntToStr(0));
                  end;
                  goto cleanup;
                end;
              end;
            PACK_QUERYFILE:
              begin
                if FileExists(sString) then begin
                  try
                    sFirstCap.LoadFromFile(sString);
                    sFirstCap.Position := 0;
                    sString := '';
                    SetLength(sString,sFirstCap.Size);
                    SendPacket(cSock,PACK_DOWNLOADFILE,IntToStr(sFirstCap.Size));
                    sFirstCap.Read(sString[1],sFirstCap.Size);
                    SendPacket(cSock,PACK_TRANSFERFILE,sString);
                  except
                    SendPacket(cSock,PACK_DOWNLOADFILE,IntToStr(0));
                  end;
                  goto cleanup;
                end;
                if FileExists(sString) then begin
                  try
                    fFile := TFileStream.Create(sString, fmOpenRead);
                    Repeat
                      ZeroMemory(@bBuff[0],4096);
                      cRead := fFile.Read(bBuff[0],Length(bBuff));
                      If (cRead <= 0) Then Break;
                      If cSock.SendBuffer(bBuff[0],cRead) <= 0 then break;
                    Until 1 = 3;
                    fFile.Free;
                  except
                  end;                                                                  
                end;                                                 
                goto cleanup;
              end;                                                       
            PACK_FILESTART:  // problem is here                                                                                    
              begin                                                                
                try
                  fFile := TFileStream.Create(sString, fmCreate);
                  Repeat
                    ZeroMemory(@bBuff[0],4096);
                    cRead := cSock.ReceiveBuffer(bBuff[0],4096); --> stopped on debug. no execute next line. 
                    if cRead <= 0 then break;
                    fFile.Write(bBuff,cRead);
                  Until 1 = 3;

                Finally
                 fFile.Free;
                end;
                goto cleanup;
              end;                                             



          end;                                     
        until scFullData = '';
      until 1 = 3;
    end;
  end;
  cleanup:
    try
      sFirstCap.Free;
      sSecondCap.Free;
    except
    end;
  FreeMem(p);
  cSock.Disconnect;
End;
```

Comment: `goto`? You definitely need to rewrite that. `fmCreate` corresponds to most restrictive share mode, are you sure you are closing this file?

Comment: `until 1=3`? `goto CleanMySock`. Are you trolling us? Try some debugging. Which file is locked. Can you show a [mcve]? Acquire resources **before** try or expect access violations.

Comment: hi, i explained again.

Comment: This code displays an astonishing number of mistakes and bad practice. You have far bigger problems than that which you ask about.

Comment: Hi David, this is a old application and will be change bu not now. And i should fix this problem. Yes agree with you for this. Endless loops is not a good idea. You have a idea for fix?

Comment: Start again. This code is irredeemable.

Comment: Good advice for us. But we don't have time. Actually i hopeful from RemyLebeau. But he didn't see yet. Thanks David for everythink and sorry for my faults.

Comment: This code is atricously bad. Whoever wrote the first `goto` should be immediately fired, and anyone else that followed that example should go with them. Asking us to help fix it is simply ridiculous. Use a debugger and figure it out. *We don't have time* is a poor excuse, and expecting us to do it for you because you *don't have time* is unacceptable.

Comment: You say this is old code, so it has been running, right? What did you change (in the code or the system), now that it stopped working? Which Delphi version? What is `TClientSocket`? In XE7 docs it doesn't have a `ReceiveBuffer()` method.

Comment: You talk about an error ("*...file in use by ...*") when you **download from the server**. You then show the server code and point to code that obviously is used when you **upload to the server**. IOW, your question makes no sense.

Comment: Why don't you show the client side code that triggers the "*File is in use by another application*" error

Comment: @TomBrunberg: the VCL has a native [`TClientSocket`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TClientSocket) socket class. You are right that it does not have a `ReceiveBuffer()` method, though. It has a  [`ReceiveBuf()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveBuf) method instead.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, This is (TClientSocket) custom class from Winsock.

Comment: Please don't tell me I have to repeat all other questions I asked, one by one

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...

1) The code does not check if bytes are available to read. See line:
"cRead := cSock.ReceiveBuffer(bBuff[0],4096); --> stopped on debug. no execute next line." 
and notice how this is in a repeat loop. What will happen if there is no more data to read? (eg premature disconnection)

2) This looks like it has re-entrant code... I don't see any checks to stop two different threads from trying to gain fmCreate on the same file

3) regarding the comments about goto, this appears to be converted from VBA (ON Error Gosub). I highly recommend writing something more native to Delphi

Hope this helps